# How can I use router.js standalone?

Tags: javascript

I wish to try out [router.js](https://github.com/tildeio/router.js) but I have hard time to do so.
From my understanding it ca be used standalone (without ember or other framework), so I have downloaded and imported it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>routerJS</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="js/router.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app-routing.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In app-routing I simply instantiate a new router

```
var router = new Router();
```

But I got

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function router.js:144

So I have double-checked the repo README and added few dependencies:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>routerJS</title>
</head>
<body>    
  <script src="js/rsvp.js"></script>
  <script src="js/route-recognizer.js"></script>
  <script src="js/router.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app-routing.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and now I get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: 
>   /js/route-recognizer.js:296

Am I still missing something here?
How can I successfully use route.js?

THANKS.

Comment: Still not able to make it work. I have played around with the dependencies but no luck.  Anyone is using it?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [this post](https://github.com/tildeio/router.js/issues/100) there seem to be a code change.

Try your setting again and create a router object like so

```
var router = new Router["default"]();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not into this issue anymore since it is 14 months old and I moved on anyway I will keep in mind.

Comment: @macsig Then it would be useful for anyone else using it ;)